# how do you watch a youtube video in a tkinter screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a gui that you can watch youtube video on.
is is even Possible?.

if so how would you do it?

Comment: No, tkinter does not have an easy way to do that. Look into PyQt or Eel.